# Get the deeper element of the DOM NODE

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to get the deeper element inside this HTML structure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">  
<div class="menu">  
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#h" >Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#f" id="current">Fruit</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#a">Apples</a></li>
                <li><a href="#o">Oranges</a></li>
                <li><a href="#b">Bananas</a></li>
                <li><a href="#p">Pears</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/about.html">About</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#c">Company Info</a></li>
                <li><a href="#l">Locations</a></li>
                <li><a href="#f">FAQ</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/contact/contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><!--closing div class for "menu"-->  
</div><!--closing div for "container"-->  
</body>

</html>
```

Looking at the structure above, the deeper element is the `<a href="#a">Apples</a>`, to try to get this element I use this code:

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('*');
var first = nodes[0];
var last = nodes[nodes.length- 1];
return last.innerHTML;
```

The problem is that the above code is returning the `'Contact Us'` value, instead of `'Apples'` or `'Pears'` (the deeper elements), which are the deeper elements of the structure of the DOM nodes.

How I can get those elements ?

Comment: `var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.menu ul ul:first-of-type a');`

Comment: Are you specifically trying to find the deepest element in the entire page, or specifically the deepest `<a>` within this menu?

Comment: @CoryDanielson Entire Page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of ways of doing this. You can think something like the element with the most amount of parents.

This way you can do it in a pretty hackish way, like this:

```
var nodes, lastNodes;
var parents = [];
do {
    lastNodes = nodes;
    nodes = document.querySelectorAll(parents.join("* > ") +  '*');
    parents.push("");
} while(nodes.length > 0);
console.log(lastNodes);
```

This will try to get nodes that have a parent (`* > *`), then will try to get nodes that have a parent that have a parent (`* > * > *`), and then nodes that have a parent that have a parent that have a parent (`* > * > * > *`) and so on...

Will stop when no nodes are received and log the latest nodes received, which will be the nodes with the lowest parents.

Answer (score 0):

Use a query selection string like so:

```js
var apples = document.querySelector(".menu ul ul:first-of-type a");
console.log(apples);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#h">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#f" id="current">Fruit</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#a">Apples</a></li>
            <li><a href="#o">Oranges</a></li>
            <li><a href="#b">Bananas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#p">Pears</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/about.html">About</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#c">Company Info</a></li>
            <li><a href="#l">Locations</a></li>
            <li><a href="#f">FAQ</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/contact/contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--closing div class for "menu"-->
  </div>
  <!--closing div for "container"-->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this JS function :

```
var DeepChildNode = (element,nodeNomber,array)=>{
    if(element.hasChildNodes()){
        nodeNomber++;
        element.childNodes.forEach((elem)=>{
            DeepChildNode(elem,nodeNomber,array);
        });
    }else{
        array.push({'element':element,'numberNodes':nodeNomber});
    }
}

var nodeNomber = 1;
var element = document.getElementById('idElement');
var array = [];
DeepChildNode(element,nodeNomber,array);

array.sort((a,b)=>{b.numberNodes-a.numberNodes});
console.table(array);
```

Answer (score -1):

try

```
document.querySelector('[href="#a"]').innerText
```

```js
let t = document.querySelector('[href="#a"]').innerText;
console.log(t);
```

```html
<div id="container">  
<div class="menu">  
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#h" >Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#f" id="current">Fruit</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#a">Apples</a></li>
                <li><a href="#o">Oranges</a></li>
                <li><a href="#b">Bananas</a></li>
                <li><a href="#p">Pears</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/about.html">About</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#c">Company Info</a></li>
                <li><a href="#l">Locations</a></li>
                <li><a href="#f">FAQ</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/contact/contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><!--closing div class for "menu"-->  
</div><!--closing div for "container"-->
```

Comment: This will not get the deeper elements of an HTML structure, but just the HTML in the question.